# Hyperlinks not working on navigation bar - not clickable

Tags: html, css

My links are not working on my navigation bar. I cannot figure out what I've done wrong. This is the code. HTML:

```
<div id="menu"
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://kerryaltmantest.info">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://kerryaltmantest.info/aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="publications">Publications</a></li>
    <li><a href="location">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="strategicinteractions">Strategic Interactions</a></li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
#menu {
    width: 950px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: cambria, Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 0px;
margin-top: -175px;
margin-left: 25px;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
}

#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2B297F;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    color: #2B297F;
    background-color: #999;
}
```

I'm sure it's just something I'm missing. If you want to see the site itself to understand what mean, you can find it at http://kerryaltmantest.info

Thank you!

Comment: You posted wrong html

Comment: actually you are searching error in wrong direction your css is not properly set

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wNHPn/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of your divs is in front of your nav bar. Through a close investigation, I found that the div `.mainrunner` is overlapping the nav bar... (Red border)
[image]

If you try to remove it from your css, you will see that your nav is now clickable... YAY!

Let me know if anything else comes up!

Comment: This COMPLETELY fixed it!!! Thank you SO much. It won't let me vote up because I'm too new :( If there's any other way I can help, I'd be happy to. THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your Parent **Div** is overrides your Menu

Here I had added Working Fiddle

```
Click on Home in Fiddle
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SiddharthShah/TEd4g/5/)
Use This CSS at your Index Page too

```
#menu {
width: 950px;
height: 35px;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: cambria, Georgia, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
background-color: #FFF;
border-radius: 0px;
/* margin-top: -175px; */
margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: In addition you have `<div id="menu" <ul>`. Make sure you close that `div`.

Comment: Sorry Sid, that was a comment for the OP, not you.